# Copy Cell With Line Breaks - Paste Values Into Separate Cells

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way in VBA to copy the contents of a cell that has multiple items in it (broken up by carriage returns), and pasting the contents into another Worksheet with each original cell value in their own cell / row?

The only way I know how to do this is double-clicking into the cell (or copying from the text box when highlighting the cell), and just pasting it into a single cell elsewhere. I wish I could do this manually, but i'm dealing with a bunch of data and doing this automatically would be wonderful.

Example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You will have to post your efforts with VBA so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of splitting cell contents in A1 on Sheet 1, into a variable `x` splitting on a VBA line-feed (normally the result of ALT+ENTER in an Excel cell)

```
x = Split(Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1").Value2, vbLf)
```

Then you can cycle through the elements of `x` using a counter `i` and put each element into column B, where `i+1` can be the row. Sample working routine:

```
Sub e()
Dim x As Variant
Dim i As Long
x = Split(Worksheets("Sheet 1").Range("A1").Value2, vbLf)
For i = LBound(x) To UBound(x)
    Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A" & i + 1).Value2 = x(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

You could avoid looping by transposing the array directly into a Range e.g. below taking split contents of `A1` and placing them in column `B`:

```
Sub e()
Dim x As Variant
x = Split(Range("A1").Value2, vbLf)
Range("B1:B" & UBound(x) + 1).Value2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(x)
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Thanks! I'll give this a shot, but the logic seems to be accurate and makes perfect sense. I appreciate it :)

Comment: It can be a little confusing to get your head round a few things, like using `+ 1` in places, because arrays always start at 0 but your rows start at 1, but once it clicks it's so useful!